# Chrome extension that overrides SSL certificate error for self-signed certificate?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension, ssl-certificate

I am trying to make an ajax request to a trusted test server through chrome extension, which is self signed. so whenever i make a request it provide me Badrequest but it works fine on orignal/main web server. So i need to override the self signed certificate in order to make a successful ajax request.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How about just adding that certificate to the certificate store in Chrome options?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate will help

Comment: ok u mean that adding manually into the store!

Comment: Clarify your question then. And the title too.

Comment: well the scenario is, i am able to make successful ajax request to main server which is ssl verfied but when i try to do that on test server which is self signed it give BAD REQUEST error.

Comment: Well, as stated, the answer would be "no way an extension would be allowed to modify the certificate store".

Comment: Well there is solution for this in c# like: "ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;"
If something like this javascript can be embedded itno content scripts.

Comment: So do i consider it that this can't be done?

Comment: Programmatically, from within the extension? Consider that it cannot.

Comment: ok thanx! Xan then i have to try on main server.

Comment: How many machines do you need for testing? If not many, why not add the certificate manually? If many, why not get a non-self-signed cert?

Comment: i tried to importing that doesn't work, even it's fine to work on main server.
And one more question now Xan, i am able to do ajax request but status i am getting is 204, and i need to insert some data into my server once i logged in.
Thanx in Advance!

Comment: If you have another question, ask a new question.

Comment: Ok Xan i just did that!.